# Android configuration/Properties file for version Name/Code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, configuration, properties

What I would like to do is create a configuration/properties/xml file in an Eclipse project that can specify project settings.

The context is that I have one application meant for 2 users. But they need to have different version and build numbers and some other parameters specific for that user.  What I would like is to have two configuration files, and then be able to specify Configuration file 1 or 2. The tricky part is that Version Code/name are specified in the android Manifest.

How is the best way to go about doing this?

Requirements:

1. Specify in one part of code which configuration/properties file to use. (ie: Config 1 or 2)
2. Android Manifest is able to reference this file for Version Code and Version Name.
3. I can dynamically reference elements of this file in my code.

Comment: Use Ant or Maven, for instance, [this](http://maven-android-plugin-m2site.googlecode.com/svn/manifest-update-mojo.html) is how Maven do it.

Comment: I have other Maven projects, unfortunately I didn't go that route with this one and was looking for something to extensible that I could easily just add in my project. See my answer below for what I came up with, which works great! Thanks for the comment though, Maven does do this rather nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a good way to do this. I simply made a "configuration" xml file that has a bunch of resources in it.

ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="version_code">6</integer>
    <string name="build_version">1.5</string>
        <string name="app_LOGO"> "R.drawable.my_logo"</string>
</resources>
```

then in my manifest I have

```
  android:versionCode="@integer/version_code"
  android:versionName="@string/build_version"
```

and then I made a configuration class.

```
public class Configuration {

    private int LOGO = 0;


    public Configuration(Context cont){

        String myResourceId = cont.getResources().getString(R.string.app_LOGO);
        String[] resourceParts = myResourceId.split("\\.");
        String packName = cont.getPackageName();
        int logo = cont.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceParts[2],               resourceParts[1], packName);

        setLogo(logo);
    }
    /**
     * @return the logo
     */
    public int getLogo() {
        return LOGO;
    }
    /**
     * set the Logo
     */
    public void setLogo(int logo) {
        LOGO = logo;
    }
}
```

Where I just call the Configuration class with the context of my activity passed into the  constructor inside of my activities onCreate Method.  Works like a charm.

Hopefully this helps someone

Cheers.